# using a small model to test asynchronous processing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've received much excellent instruction on Stack Overflow, especially regarding my feeble attempts to incorporate asynchronous processing in a recent web application. To narrow down some issues to their minimum, I created a very small HTML/javascript page to play with getJSON and look at some behavior mentioned by jfriend00. So far as I can see, this is a legitimate program, but although IE9 runs it, FireFox emits some text, then hangs/infinitely loops/whatever, while Chrome shows only the H1 (FireFox declined to do so) and the last string. Obviously, there is something horribly wrong with this code and I'm not seeing it. How about you?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>testing 2</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function buildTree() {
      $.getJSON('MurakiMaida.json', function(data) {
        document.write("how about here?<br>");
        $.each(data.person, function(i, xdata) {
    document.write(xdata.id + "<br>");
        });
    });
    document.write("<br>what are we doing here?");
    }
    buildTree();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` is probably the culprit.

I don't understand what exactly you are try to do, but `document.write` should only be used while the page is loading.  Actually it is probably better to never use it.*

Create a `<div id='foo'/>` and write to it such as `$('#foo').append($("<div>"+xdata.id+"</div>")`

*`document.write` was the way to use Javascript to add HTML to a document back in the days before the DOM existed.  It still exists for backward compatibility, but should be avoided.*

Comment: Absolutely correct, thank you. All three browsers work identically now. All display only the "how about here?" string.

Comment: I spoke too quickly. IE9 always shows only the "stock" HTML: the H1 and a comment I entered at the same time as I put in the DIV you recommended.
   Chrome always shows the JSON IDs from the file below the string "how about here?"
   And Mozilla shows the same as Chrome _until_ I add an alert upon entering the single function. When I do that, Mozilla exhibits IE9's behavior: no IDs, no strings. Just the stock HTML.
   Even if I don't understand why this is happening, it was the purpose of the experiment! -- Michael